# Nokia T20 WiFi (TA-1392) EDL mode activation?

Tags: rom-flashing, operating-system, nokia, download-mode

I have discovered that my Nokia T20 WiFi tablet (TA-1392), was hard-bricked after clean-erasing it while trying to install an Android 13 GSI. Later research pointed me to my tablet’s EDL (Emergency Download) mode. Can anyone show me how I can get into EDL mode on this model of Nokia tablet?

Sincerely, 
Saturanium